# how to configure maven profile to run webapps on tomcat or on glassfish from netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish

I've been using maven for a while now.minimum setup and so far so good.
I've always been using tomcat but now i would like to see what glassfish has to  offer
but most of project are from subversion where i work with other people.
so not to force them to install glassfish i wanted to create a maven profile 
so that we can switch from tomcat to glassfish.

in netbeans we have this

```
 <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat60</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
```

to indicate that the webapp should be run on v6 of tomcat.
i've read the profile documentation and i sort of don't know where and how to configure that.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

thanks for reading and for helping...

Answer (score 0):

The Cargo plugin may help you to achieve the requirement. Please visit the following link

1. The web site: http://cargo.codehaus.org/
2. The very quick start: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin
3. The useful articles: http://cargo.codehaus.org/Articles